# Gnuplot Plotting from a file using certain number of rows

Tags: plot, gnuplot

I have data in some text file which has 1000 rows and 2 columns.I want to plot it in first 10 rows and second ten rows and so on with different line style and colour using GNUPLOT. How can i do it? Thank you very much in advance.

I have tried plotting it with  " plot "filename.txt" every ::1::10 using 1:2 with lines ".
But its all coming in same colour.

Comment: What does "different line style" mean and include for you? line width and dash type and maybe pointtype (and point size) if plotting style is `with linespoints` and colour? All of them or only some of them? Should the groups of 10 rows each be connected by lines or not?

Comment: Each Group of 10 points should have same style or colour so that i can tell separately the pattern of each group of 10 data.It can be with line also but what i want is each group of 10 point should have different line colour than another group of 10 points.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to have different line color you can use `linecolor variable` (check `help lc variable`) and use the pseudocolumn 0 (basically, zero-based row number index), check `help pseudocolumns`). However, there is no variable linewidth or dash type. If you want that you have to do it differently.

Check the following example (with just 100 random data points).
However, if you have 1000 data rows and 10 lines each you will need 100 colors. Then a solution with palette might be better. But this depends on your exact case what you want to show.

**Script:** (`keyentry` requires gnuplot>=5.2.6)

```
### plot each N rows with different color
reset session

# create some random test data
set table $Data
    plot [0:100] y0=0 '+' u 1:(y0=y0+rand(0)-0.5) w table
unset table

myColors   = "0xff0000 0x00ff00 0x0000ff 0xff00ff 0xffff00 0x00ffff 0xffaa00 0x00ffaa 0x00aaff 0xffaaaa"
myColor(i) = int(word(myColors,i))

set key out noautotitle
N = 10

plot $Data u 1:2:(myColor(int($0)/N+1)) w l lc rgb var lw 2, \
     for [i=0:N-1] keyentry w l lc rgb myColor(i+1) lw 2 title sprintf("Row %d to %d",i*N,(i+1)*N-1)
### end of script
```

**Result:**

[image]